# Performance Analysis for TI TM4C129E on µVision IDE

Tags: arm, keil, texas-instruments

I am looking to do a performance analysis (using the µVision Performance Analyzer tool) to benchmark the runtime of functions in a program written in C and ASM. The program runs as it should, and I'm able to use the Performance Analyzer in debug simulation. However, when I debug the code on the actual environment (that is, NOT in simulation) I am unable to use the Performance Analyzer.

The program works as it should when run on the target environment, confirmed by checking variable values using the Watch windows. Would anyone be able to tell me how I can use the Performance Analyzer when debugging on the actual environment? Or, would anyone be able to direct me to sources relevant to my issue?

NB: The program does not call to any peripherals.

Thanks.